# Reading text file until a space and storing several values

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating an application to read and display Pokemon stats. Currently, I have 6 txt files, one for each stat. I have 6 arrays reading each txt file and displaying each stat in a label.

I want to condense this information into a single text file, splitting each stat by a " " to keep each Pokemon's data on a single line.

Current code if it helps explain the idea better:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;

namespace Pokedex
{
    public partial class Pokedex : Form
    {
        public Pokedex()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Read stat data from text files into string arrays
        string[] HP = File.ReadAllLines("HP.txt");
        string[] Atk = File.ReadAllLines("Atk.txt");
        string[] Def = File.ReadAllLines("Def.txt");
        string[] SpAtk = File.ReadAllLines("SpAtk.txt");
        string[] SpDef = File.ReadAllLines("SpDef.txt");
        string[] Spe = File.ReadAllLines("Spe.txt");

        private void cbxPokemon_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get array index of currently selected Pokemon
            int index = cbxPokemon.SelectedIndex;

            //Get integer values out of the string arrays for appropriate use
            int intHP = int.Parse(HP[index]);
            int intAtk = int.Parse(Atk[index]);
            int intDef = int.Parse(Def[index]);
            int intSpAtk = int.Parse(SpAtk[index]);
            int intSpDef = int.Parse(SpDef[index]);
            int intSpe = int.Parse(Spe[index]);

            //Update labels with stat values in string forme, could also assign intStat.ToString()
            lblDexNum.Text = (index + 1).ToString("d3");

            lblHP.Text = HP[index];
            lblAtk.Text = Atk[index];
            lblDef.Text = Def[index];
            lblSpAtk.Text = SpAtk[index];
            lblSpDef.Text = SpDef[index];
            lblSpe.Text = Spe[index];

            lblBST.Text = (intHP + intAtk + intDef + intSpAtk + intSpDef + intSpe).ToString();

            //Update bar width based on stat value
            barHP.Width = intHP;
            barAtk.Width = intAtk;
            barDef.Width = intDef;
            barSpAtk.Width = intSpAtk;
            barSpDef.Width = intSpDef;
            barSpe.Width = intSpe;

            //Disable Previous and Next buttons when they cannot be used
            if (index == 0) { btnPrev.Enabled = false; }
            else { btnPrev.Enabled = true; }

            if (index == cbxPokemon.Items.Count - 1) { btnNext.Enabled = false; }
            else { btnNext.Enabled = true; }
        }

        private void btnPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbxPokemon.SelectedIndex -= 1;
        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbxPokemon.SelectedIndex += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, the file would contain the 6 stats, for example "100 90 80 70 60 50" on each line, with each of those valued being stored.

Is there a simple way to read until a space, store that value, and keep doing that until the end of the line?

Comment: So if your ideal situation is to have each stat on a separate line in a **single** file, why not take that approach?  It's actually a **lot easier** to do.

Comment: Ideally I would have 6 stats on each line. If I were to have one stat on every line in a single file (6 lines for each Pokemon), creating and managing that file would be a pain, as it would eventually be 4332 lines long.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood what you meant in that comment, your idea situation is one pokemon per line, i.e. 6 stats separated by a space on a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is very simple to do.  You can use the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method to break apart the lines into parsable pieces.

You can read the stats file in the same way you are now, except you would only need to read one file instead of six:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("PokemonStats.txt");
```

Then, inside your `cbxPokemon_SelectedIndexChanged` method, you can retrieve the stats for a Pokemon like this:

```
//Get integer values out of the string for appropriate use
string line = lines[index];
string[] parts = line.Split(' ');

int intHP = int.Parse(parts[0]);
int intAtk = int.Parse(parts[1]);
int intDef = int.Parse(parts[2]);
int intSpAtk = int.Parse(parts[3]);
int intSpDef = int.Parse(parts[4]);
int intSpe = int.Parse(parts[5]);
```

Of course this assumes there will always be exactly 6 integer stats per line and they will all be in a specific order.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much for the input.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //list to store stats
        List<string[]> pokemonStats = new List<string[]>();
        //get a reader on the file
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt"))
        {
            //while we still have lines to read
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                //get the line of stats
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                //split it on the ' ' character and store it in our list of pokemon stats
                pokemonStats.Add(line.Split(' '));
            }
        }

        //we have them all so do something, like print to screen
        foreach (string[] pokemon in pokemonStats)
        {
            foreach (string stat in pokemon)
                Console.Write(stat + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Where TextFile1.txt contains; which also happens to be the output...

```
 1 1 1 1 1 1
 2 2 2 2 2 2
 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally, the file would contain the 6 stats, for example "100 90 80 70 60 50" on each line, with each of those valued being stored.

So this solution is actually very simple, assuming you have a file that looks like this:

```
100
90
80
70
60
50
```

You could write code that looks like this:

```
public string[] ReadStats(string fileName)
{
   return File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
}
```

This would return:

```
[ "100", "90", "80", "70", "60", "50" ]
```

This is obviously an over-simplified version that does not checking on whether the file exists, whether there are more than 6 lines, etc.  But it gets the idea across, and you could enhance it to suit your needs.

The answer to your main question:

> Is there a simple way to read until a space, store that value, and keep doing that until the end of the line?

This is a bit more complicated, but this should work:

```
public IEnumerable<string[]> ReadAllPokemonStats(string fileName)
{
     List<string[]> allPokemon = new List<string[]>();
     string[] allStats = new string[6];

     var allText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

     int nextStatIndex = 0;
     string thisStat;
     for(int i=0; i < allText.Length; i++)
     {
         var nextChar = allText[i];
         if(nextChar == ' ')
         {
             allStats[nextStatIndex] = thisStat;
             nextStatIndex++;
             continue;
         }

         if(nextChar == '\r') 
         {
             allPokemon.Add(allStats);
             nextStatIndex = 0;
             allStats = new string[6];
             continue;
         }

         thisStat += nextChar.ToString();
     }

     return allPokemon;
}
```

Again, the above code is not perfect, for example it reads the entire file into memory so there's a potential attack vector there.  It also does not ensure that the stats are actually numeric, but neither did your code (it would just blow up on the `int.Parse()`).  But again, it gives you the general idea.  You can see this approach is actually a lot more complex that reading each stat line by line.

Comment: Updated a little based on a better understanding of your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I will definitely try this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that each file is a one column file that represents one type of stat. If this is correct, you can try this:

Perhaps creating a class the represents all the stats that you are loading and then treat that as an array or a dictionary to fetch the proper stat or to create a single stat file.

```
    public class PokemonStat
    {
        public int Hp { get; set; }
        public int Atk { get; set; }
        public int Def { get; set; }
        public int SpAtk { get; set; }
        public int SpDef { get; set; }
        public int Spe { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in your executing file:

```
        var newPokemanData = new Dictionary<int, PokemonStat>();
        var fileNames = new string[] { "Hp.txt", "Atk.txt", "Def.txt", "SpAtk.txt", "SpDef.txt", "Spe.txt" }

        foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
        {
            var lineNumber = 0;

            using (var stream = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                while (!stream.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var singleStat = stream.ReadLine();

                    if (!newPokemanData.Keys.Contains(lineNumber))
                    {
                        newPokemanData.Add(lineNumber, new PokemonStat());
                    }


                    switch(fileName)
                    {
                        case "Hp.txt":
                            newPokemanData[lineNumber].Hp = int.Parse(singleStat);
                            break;
                        case "Atk.txt":
                            newPokemanData[lineNumber].Atk = int.Parse(singleStat);
                            break;
                        case "Def.txt":
                            newPokemanData[lineNumber].Def = int.Parse(singleStat);
                            break;
                        case "SpAtk.txt":
                            newPokemanData[lineNumber].SpAtk = int.Parse(singleStat);
                            break;
                        case "SpDef.txt":
                            newPokemanData[lineNumber].SpDef = int.Parse(singleStat);
                            break;
                        case "Spe.txt":
                            newPokemanData[lineNumber].Spe = int.Parse(singleStat);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Error");
                            break;
                    }

                    lineNumber++;

                }
            }
        }


        using (var unifiedStats = new StreamWriter("unifieldFile.txt"))
        {

            foreach (var line in newPokemanData.Keys)
            {
                //write to a file
                unifiedStats.WriteLine(newPokemanData[line].Hp.ToString() + " " +
                                        newPokemanData[line].Atk.ToString() + " " +
                                        newPokemanData[line].Def.ToString() + " " +
                                        newPokemanData[line].SpAtk.ToString() + " " +
                                        newPokemanData[line].SpDef.ToString() + " " +
                                        newPokemanData[line].Spe.ToString() + " "                                         
                    );

            }
        }
        //
```

Comment: I have not compiled this code, but the idea is there.